# BeautifulSoup splitting scraped string into three rows

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, rows

When I scrape text via BS it prints out all of the data as a one string. For example it prints

```
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
  ...
<td>99</td>
```

as

```
1
2
.
.
99
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to print it out into three rows:

```
1    2    3
.    .    .
.    .    .
97   98   99
```

ATM my code is

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("http://www.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
for link in soup.find_all("td"):
    print(link.string)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do simply like in the below example,

```
In [23]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [24]: s = """<td>1</td>
    ...: <td>2</td>
    ...: <td>3</td>
    ...: <td>4</td>
    ...: <td>5</td>
    ...: <td>6</td>"""

In [4]: soup = BeautifulSoup(s)

In [25]: td = [i.string for i in soup.find_all("td")]

In [26]: td
Out[26]: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

In [28]: for i in range(0, len(td), 3):
    ...:     print('    '.join(td[i:i+3]))
    ...:     
1    2    3
4    5    6
```